# tables not creating in spring boot v2.2.6.RELEASE postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, connection

## In spring boot table is not creating in database app running without error tried spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop solution and spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true but still it is not creating table

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/human
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema =public
spring.datasource.username =postgres
spring.datasource.password =wetech
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
server.port=8000
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

console

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:49961,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.IdeaIC2019.2\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\arjunmore\New folder\human\target\classes;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.18.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.5\aspectjweaver-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.12.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.24.0-GA\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.8\byte-buddy-1.10.8.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.1.1.Final\jandex-2.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.2\txw2-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.8\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.1\stax-ex-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.16\FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\modelmapper\modelmapper\2.3.5\modelmapper-2.3.5.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.11.0.rc1\jackson-annotations-2.11.0.rc1.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\io\jsonwebtoken\jjwt\0.9.1\jjwt-0.9.1.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.10.3\jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.10.3\jackson-core-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-jasper\9.0.33\tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.33.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.33\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-annotations-api\9.0.33\tomcat-annotations-api-9.0.33.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.33\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.33.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jdt\ecj\3.18.0\ecj-3.18.0.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.12.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.12.1\log4j-api-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.30\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.25\snakeyaml-1.25.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.2\HikariCP-3.4.2.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-security-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.2.2.RELEASE\spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.2.2.RELEASE\spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-devtools-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.2.11\postgresql-42.2.11.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.2.2.RELEASE\spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.13.2\assertj-core-3.13.2.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.10.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.10.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.10.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.33\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.2.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.2.5.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.realtion.human.HumanApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49961', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-04-02 15:59:09.069  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] com.realtion.human.HumanApplication      : Starting HumanApplication on LAPTOP-CIPTEI01 with PID 8052 (E:\arjunmore\New folder\human\target\classes started by WeTech_Digital in E:\arjunmore\New folder\human)
2020-04-02 15:59:09.074  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] com.realtion.human.HumanApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-02 15:59:09.165  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\WeTech_Digital\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/WeTech_Digital/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/WeTech_Digital/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/WeTech_Digital/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/WeTech_Digital/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/WeTech_Digital/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/C:/Users/WeTech_Digital/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2020-04-02 15:59:09.166  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-04-02 15:59:09.166  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-04-02 15:59:09.852  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-02 15:59:09.870  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-04-02 15:59:11.232  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8000 (http)
2020-04-02 15:59:11.247  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-02 15:59:11.247  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-04-02 15:59:11.524  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-04-02 15:59:11.529  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-02 15:59:11.529  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2363 ms
2020-04-02 15:59:11.828  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-04-02 15:59:11.913  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-04-02 15:59:12.051  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-04-02 15:59:12.152  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-02 15:59:12.286  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-04-02 15:59:12.310  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2020-04-02 15:59:12.642  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-04-02 15:59:12.651  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-04-02 15:59:12.666  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-04-02 15:59:12.757  WARN 8052 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-04-02 15:59:12.959  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-02 15:59:13.261  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 145e5704-392b-4917-9e1d-39e864f84e4a

2020-04-02 15:59:13.416  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@74a566f9, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6063df47, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4f366407, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7dcc51fa, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6cb9a4cd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@516e6a13, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@1a47e831, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@74ec2d32, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2ade0195, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@75231a41, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@518d089a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5e8ec2cc, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7bfe3616, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@43c0ac9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@78728d25]
2020-04-02 15:59:13.521  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8000 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-02 15:59:13.525  INFO 8052 --- [  restartedMain] com.realtion.human.HumanApplication      : Started HumanApplication in 4.945 seconds (JVM running for 5.644)
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.realtion</groupId>
    <artifactId>human</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>human</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0.rc1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: And you have Entites? And how does your package structure look like? Are the enties in the package tree below the SpringBootApplication?

Comment: `
@Entity
public class Events  {
}
`
yes annoted with @entity

Answer (score 1):

I fixed issue problem is with entity package address while creating project 
i misspelled word **realtion** but in main spring boot class i wrote correct spelling that is **relation** thats why spring was not able find path and table were not creating .

```
@EntityScan("com.realtion.human.model")
```

Comment: You should avoid EntityScan if you make your package structure as Spring Boot recommends you don't needit

Comment: @SimonMartinelli why should be avoid? If is used explicitly why should arise(s) problem(s) - if is the case